# Undertow authentication across multiple pages

Tags: security, authentication, wildfly, undertow

I would like to make a login page where users provide credentials and then have other pages check if the user is authenticated before serving those internal pages in Undertow.

While the example shows how to authenticate a user (for what will eventually turn into a login page), if the user were to navigate to another page after authenticating, how do I test if that new page request was been made by the authenticated user?

I have referenced http://undertow.io/documentation/core/security.html and https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/undertow/examples/security/basic.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ancient question no one answered, but I did manage to learn about [Keycloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org/) which is Wildfly (Undertow) + SSO/Secure login.